# PHP: $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST empty on input form evaluation

Tags: php, input, request

a question that is being asked many times as far as I can see.
Lots of postings concerning this issue also on this website, for example

here: [$_POST empty on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661677/post-empty-on-form-submit)
and here:
[$_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776911/post-get-and-request-empty)

But none of them cured my problem.

I´ve a simple HTML input form with a submit button.
Its "name" tag is set.

My php.ini settings are:

```
request_order = "GP"
variables_order = "GPCS"
register_globals = Off
```

The input data is being processed in the Method "action" in "Util.php".
The code for the input form as well as the Util::action method has been provided by our professor (its an assignment for university), as we developed a similar project during the php seminar.

Unfortunately, the $_REQUEST array stays empty in my project.

here´s the source code of the input form:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/bootstrap.php');


if (AuthenticationManager::isAuthenticated()) {
    Util::redirect("index.php");
}

$userName = isset($_REQUEST['userName']) ? $_REQUEST['userName'] : null;
?>

<?php
require_once('inc/header.php');
?>

<h2>Login</h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo Util::action('login'); ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User name:</th>
            <td><input name="userName"
                value="<?php echo htmlentities($userName); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Password:</th>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name='login' />
</form>

<?php
require_once('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

and here the Util.php:

```
    <?php

    class Util extends BaseObject {
    // Bereinigen eines Strings für die HTML-Ausgabe
    /**
     * @param string $string
     * @return string
     */
    public static function escape($string) {
        return nl2br(htmlentities($string));

    }



    /**
     * @param string $action
     * @param array $params
     */
    public static function action($action, array $params = null ) {

        //enters ELSE branch as IF branch evaluates to false
        //(because $_REQUEST contains 0 elements
        //(so do $_GET and $_POST)
        $page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        //just an attempt for hardcore debugging...
        $req = array_merge($_GET, $_POST); 
        $page = count($req); //evaluates to zero

        $res = '/lib/controller.php?action='.rawurlencode($action).'&page='.rawurlencode($page);
        //result is: localhost/lib/controller.php?action=login&page=0

        if ( is_array($params) ) {
            foreach ( $params as $name => $value ) {
                $res.='&'.rawurlencode($name).'='.rawurlencode($value);
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }

    public static function redirect($page = null) {
        if ( $page == null ) {
            $page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }

        header('Location: '.$page);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a tinyint (from MySQL DB) to boolean (PHP)
     * @param int $tinyInt
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function tinyintToBoolean($tinyInt) {
        if ($tinyInt == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

/**
 * bootstrap must be included in every callable view 
 * 
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'lib/' . $class . '.php';

});

// create session
SessionContext::create();

//require_once('lib/data/DataManager_' . $class . '.php');
require_once('lib/DataManager.php');

?>
```

Comment: You might already know this, but in pure PHP files theres no need for the closing `?>` PHP tag, it just leaves more room for error regarding output being sent to the browser.

Comment: What is the URL you call your form with? Is page already in there? Also, what does DataManager do?